# Custom customer account controller

Tags: magento2, customer, controllers, customer-account

Today I had to create new controller, checking something while registering (ajax one). But every try of reaching it ends up in login page. I have found plugin `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Plugin/Account.php:29` which has some empty property `allowedActions`. Is it blocking from dispatching my action? Is it any way to omit that/add my action to that array?

Does it comes along with `vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/frontend/sections.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to this list using `di.xml`. This because the plugin expects an array of allowed actions to passed into the constructor (which is defined in di.xml).

Take a look:

```
<?php
...
class Account
{
...
    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        array $allowedActions = []
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->allowedActions = $allowedActions;
    }
...
}
```

In the customer module take a look at `etc/frontend/di.xml`. You'll find the following definition:

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="allowedActions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="create" xsi:type="string">create</item>
            <item name="login" xsi:type="string">login</item>
            <item name="logoutsuccess" xsi:type="string">logoutsuccess</item>
            <item name="forgotpassword" xsi:type="string">forgotpassword</item>
            <item name="forgotpasswordpost" xsi:type="string">forgotpasswordpost</item>
            <item name="resetpassword" xsi:type="string">resetpassword</item>
            <item name="resetpasswordpost" xsi:type="string">resetpasswordpost</item>
            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="string">confirm</item>
            <item name="confirmation" xsi:type="string">confirmation</item>
            <item name="createpassword" xsi:type="string">createpassword</item>
            <item name="createpost" xsi:type="string">createpost</item>
            <item name="loginpost" xsi:type="string">loginpost</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

So, what you can do is create your own `etc/frontend/di.xml`, and add your action to this array. That would look a little like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Plugin\Account">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="allowedActions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="[myAction]" xsi:type="string">[myAction]</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: hi, what exactly sections.xml file do?

Comment: @jafarpinjar You can read up about them here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html#invalidate-private-content